# Scrollbar start from bottom Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a scrollbar in a div element with `height` and `overflow` css, I want the div to start from a bottom. **I did that in javascript** [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eqycfrp2/1/)

```js
var objDiv = document.getElementById("scrolldiv");
objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollHeight;
```

```css
#scrolldiv{
  width:115px;
  height:100px;
  overflow:auto;
  border: 2px black solid;
}
```

```html
<div id="scrolldiv">
 <ul>
          <li>Instagram</li>
          <li>WhatsApp</li>
          <li>Oculus</li>
          <li>Instagram</li>
          <li>WhatsApp</li>
          <li>Oculus</li>
          <li>Instagram</li>
          <li>WhatsApp</li>
          <li>Oculus</li>
          <li>Instagram</li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

**How to apply my javascript code in reactjs?**

```
class ShoppingList extends React.Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            pageNumber: 1
        }
    }


  render() {
    return (
      <div className="shopping-list"  id="scrolldiv">
        <ul>
          <li>Instagram</li>
          <li>WhatsApp</li>
          <li>Oculus</li>
          <li>Instagram</li>
          <li>WhatsApp</li>
          <li>Oculus</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using [React Refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) to get hold of the element:

```
class ShoppingList extends React.Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            pageNumber: 1
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        let shoppingListContainer = document.getElementById("scrolldiv");
        shoppingListContainer.scrollTop = shoppingListContainer.scrollHeight;
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="shopping-list" id="scrolldiv">
                <ul>
                    <li>Instagram</li>
                    <li>WhatsApp</li>
                    <li>Oculus</li>
                    <li>Instagram</li>
                    <li>WhatsApp</li>
                    <li>Oculus</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Well, [Mui Dialog](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/3618) component doesn't appear to have a hook to run function when dialog is shown, however you can move the scrollposition logic into `handleOpen` method, like below:

```
class App extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            open: false,
        }
    }

    handleOpen = () => {
        this.setState({ open: true });
        // hack
        setTimeout(() => {
            let shoppingListContainer = document.getElementById("scrolldiv");
            if (shoppingListContainer !== null) {
                shoppingListContainer.scrollTop = shoppingListContainer.scrollHeight;
            }
        }, 100);
    };
    handleClose = () => {
        this.setState({ open: false });
    };

    render() {
        return (
        <MuiThemeProvider>
        <div>
            <RaisedButton label="Alert" onClick={this.handleOpen} />
            <Dialog
            title="Dialog With Actions"
            modal={false}
            open={this.state.open}
            onRequestClose={this.handleClose}
            >

                <div className="shopping-list" id="scrolldiv" 
                style={{
                width: 125,
                height: 100,
                overflow: 'auto',
                border: '2px black solid'
                }}>
                <ul>
                    <li>Instagram</li>
                    <li>WhatsApp</li>
                    <li>Oculus</li>
                    <li>Instagram</li>
                    <li>WhatsApp</li>
                    <li>Oculus</li>
                </ul>
                </div>
            </Dialog>

        </div>
        </MuiThemeProvider>
        );
    }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: Thank you it works but unfortunately when I'm trying to put the div inside a Dialog of Material-UI design it won't work :(   Do you have any idea why? I'm getting error `Cannot read property 'scrollHeight' of undefined` I did an example [https://codesandbox.io/s/9r3x0nq0o](https://codesandbox.io/s/9r3x0nq0o)

Comment: In your case, I think it would be quicker to use a slightly hackish approach ```getElementById``` something like ```let shoppingListContainer = document.getElementById("scrolldiv");``` updated my answer, other ways to go about this are [here](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/issues/1933)

Comment: Very Thank you to your reply, unfortunately it doesn't work https://codesandbox.io/s/9r3x0nq0o

Comment: Ah, just had a look, scrollPositioning logic will have to be moved to ```handleOpen``` - updated my answer above